# How do I hide, close, or collapse the Google Help Assistant sidebar in Google Workspaces?

Tags: google-workspace

How do I hide, close, or collapse the Google Help Assistant sidebar in Google Workspaces?
simple enough function; no apparent way to collapse, remove, turn off, hide the help sidebar on support.google.com web pages.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. What do you mean by "Google Workspaces"? What do you mean by "Google Help Assistant sidebar"? support.google.com is mentioned but it is very ambigous. Please add a couple of specific examples.

Comment: do you mean this https://support.google.com/businesssitebuilder/answer/1660706?hl=en